# My scrapy Spider isn't crawling pages, 'Crawled 0 pages, scraped 0 items. Can't seem to find what's wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

When running 'scrapy crawl newegg' in my console i'm hit with 'Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min). I have tried looking up many fixes none of which have worked. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
# web scrapes newegg page for product price
import scrapy

class NeweggSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'newegg'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.newegg.com/team-32gb-288-pin-ddr4-sdram/p/N82E16820331426?Item=N82E16820331426&cm_sp=Homepage_SS-_-P0_20-331-426-_-08282022'
    ]
        
    def parse(self, response):

        for product in response.css('div.page-section-innder'):
            yield {
                'name': product.css('h1.prodcut-title::text').get(),
                'price': product.css('li.price-current strong::text').get()
            }
```

This is the console log after running 'scrapy crawl newegg'. As you can see it is crawling 0 pages and scraping 0 items, I cannot look through the console log to see what is wrong.

```
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.2 started (bot: newegg)
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.1.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 2.0.1, Twisted 22.4.0, Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022), cryptography 37.0.4, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'newegg',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'newegg.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['newegg.spiders']}
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 5d3a6b25365f91b1
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.newegg.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 2120593134576 on C:\Users\Casey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 2120593134576 acquired on C:\Users\Casey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 2120593134576 on C:\Users\Casey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 2120593134576 released on C:\Users\Casey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.newegg.com/team-32gb-288-pin-ddr4-sdram/p/N82E16820331426?Item=N82E16820331426&cm_sp=Homepage_SS-_-P0_20-331-426-_-08282022> (referer: None)
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 550,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 42150,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.25123,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 29, 3, 12, 38, 921346),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 181561,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 29, 3, 12, 38, 670116)}
2022-08-28 22:12:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your first css selector. But even after fixing that your selectors don't seem to be working.  It is successfully grabbing half of the price but it doesn't seem to work for the product name or the other half of the price field.

A fix for the name selector would be to just apply the selector directly to the response instead of chaining it from the product, and a better solution that can grab the whole price text would be to use an xpath expression.

For example:

```
# web scrapes newegg page for product price
import scrapy

class NeweggSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'newegg'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.newegg.com/team-32gb-288-pin-ddr4-sdram/p/N82E16820331426?Item=N82E16820331426&cm_sp=Homepage_SS-_-P0_20-331-426-_-08282022'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        price = response.xpath("//li[@class='price-current']//*/text()").getall()
        price_string = ''.join(price)
        yield {
            "name": response.css("h1.product-title::text").get(),
            "price": price_string
        }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'name': 'Team T-FORCE DARK Za 32GB (2 x 16GB) 288-Pin PC RAM DDR4 3600 (PC4 28800) Desktop Memory (FOR AMD) Model TDZAD432G3600HC18JDC01', 
'price': '89.99'}
```